# Is there an iPhone/iPad application that demonstrates the various API's like the Google Android API Demos app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

Here is a link to the Google app 
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not seen anything just like that, though there are tons of working app projects from Apple designed to demonstrate various APIs.

**[iOS Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#navigation/)**

Click **Sample Code** in the lefthand menu and then sort by framework.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I was aware of the volumes of Apple sample code available, but the nice thing about the Google API Demos app is it includes very simple examples of various APIs which also functions as a compact code repository to draw from.  Maybe when XCode 4 finally gets release we can use the code snippet feature.

Comment: Agreed, super-simple examples would definitely help, and a good code repository would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There's tons of sample code:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code